# Deleting only the few files dynamically in a folder?

Tags: r

I have a few files in a folder called "Output" in Desktop. There are CSV files in that folder named - DATA, abc_DATA, de_DATA, f_data, xyzj_data. So every time, I will always have one DATA file, and the number of other with prefix_DATA varies based on my inputs to the program. I want to delete all the files with prefic_DATA CSV files except DATA file.

Could you please help me with R Code I should have to get the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
file.remove(dir(pattern = "_DATA"))
```

Comment: If it worked, you may consider ticking the check mark to indicate it's an accepted answer ;)